# How is the native implementation of the map method so fast?

Tags: javascript, performance, dictionary, testing

How is the native implementation of the map method so fast?

I reimplemented it, and it's still around 2 times slower than the `.map` method called to iterate over an array.

Here's my code:

```
Array.prototype.toMap = function(cb, ctx) {
  if(typeof cb != 'function') {
    return
  }

  var
    result = [],
    len = this.length

  for(var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    result.push(cb.call(ctx, this[i], i, this))
  }

  return result
}
```

I'm testing against the following code:

```
var
  myArr = [10, 10, 10],
  myObj = {
    addOne: function(n) {
      return n + 1
    }
  }

myArr.toMap(function(value, key, array) {
  return this.addOne(value)
}, myObj) // [11, 11, 11]
```

Just for comparison, I created another method based on the "official" MDN polyfill (https://mzl.la/2EeddOh). Here are the results:

```
mdn map polyfill: 0.318ms
my map reimplementation: 0.058ms
built in map: 0.021ms

mdn map polyfill: 0.433ms
my map reimplementation: 0.080ms
built in map: 0.029ms

mdn map polyfill: 0.334ms
my map reimplementation: 0.056ms
built in map: 0.029ms

mdn map polyfill: 0.429ms
my map reimplementation: 0.057ms
built in map: 0.021ms

mdn map polyfill: 0.333ms
my map reimplementation: 0.056ms
built in map: 0.021ms
```

What are your thoughts?

Comment: OMG... That MDN polyfill is terrible, haha. So slow.

Comment: What runtime are you using? Also, imagine if you could write a common routine directly in C or C++ and have the JavaScript interpreter call that directly: that could easily be loads faster than any JavaScript implementation.

Comment: Node v9, Mac OS X High Sierra. That makes sense. Perhaps Node uses C++ directly instead of Javascript...

Comment: @LuisFelipeZaguini It *does*

Comment: It would be very interesting to check their code. Is there any way to do that? I'm not sure Node is open sourced. But you have to admit: I made a very good job with that reimplementation, lol.

Comment: Node uses V8 by default... all of the code is open source. https://github.com/v8/v8 And yes, the native map method being called is a C++ function.

Comment: Any clue on where it is on the repo?

Comment: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/c38cb367e76ee8bd87719dd3699254e74f8ebfd1/src/builtins/builtins-array-gen.cc#L2536

Answer (score 0):

As discussed in the comments, the answer is that very frequently used functions might be implemented in a language closer to the hardware in order to provide higher performance.

For Node.js specifically, this is in the V8 engine and V8 does implement `Array.prototype.map` in C++ directly: https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/c38cb367e76ee8bd87719dd3699254e74f8ebfd1/src/builtins/builtins-array-gen.cc#L2536